# Merge pdf using Docotic.Pdf Library

Tags: pdf

I already have a class that does this but I want you to finish programming a NEW class using the Docotic.Pdf Library Their website for your reference is: http://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/

this code which I write.

```
`Public Class Form1

Private Sub butMergePdfs_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butMergePdfs.Click

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Load some sample PDF files into the string arrays
    'In production it will read the files into the string arrays
    'from a database.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim strMergeFiles(3) As String
    Dim strMergeTitles(3) As String
    strMergeFiles(0) = "D:\Nayeem_Mansoori\Cis_Projects\Cis_Projects\SanjayVerma\PdfMergeTest\PDF_1.pdf"
    strMergeFiles(1) = "D:\Nayeem_Mansoori\Cis_Projects\Cis_Projects\SanjayVerma\PdfMergeTest\PDF_2.pdf"
    strMergeFiles(2) = "D:\Nayeem_Mansoori\Cis_Projects\Cis_Projects\SanjayVerma\PdfMergeTest\PDF_3.pdf"
    'strMergeFiles(0) = "C:\Temp\PDF_1.pdf"
    'strMergeFiles(1) = "C:\Temp\PDF_2.pdf"
    'strMergeFiles(2) = "C:\Temp\PDF_3.pdf"
    strMergeTitles(0) = "OUTLINE_1"
    strMergeTitles(1) = "OUTLINE_2"
    strMergeTitles(2) = "OUTLINE_3"
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        'This shows how the old class worked. The new class needs to work
        'with exactly the same parameters.
        ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
       'Dim myMerge As New clsMerge_OLD
       'Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName & ".pdf"
       'Dim strOutputFileAndPath As String = "C:\temp\" & strFileName
        Dim myMerge As New clsMerge_NEW
        Dim strFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName & ".pdf"
        Dim strOutputFileAndPath As String = "C:\temp\" & strFileName
        'Merge the files.
        myMerge.MergeFiles(strMergeFiles, strMergeTitles, strOutputFileAndPath)
        'Shop any merge errors.
        If myMerge.Errors <> "" Then
            MsgBox(myMerge.Errors)
        End If
        'Open the merged PDF
        Process.Start(strOutputFileAndPath)
        myMerge = Nothing
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        MsgBox(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    End Sub
End Class
    Imports BitMiracle.Docotic.Pdf

Public Class clsMerge_NEW

    Private mstrErrors As String
    Private mboolCurrentFileIsIrefStream As Boolean
    Private mboolPadPageCountToEven As Boolean
    Private mRand As Random

    Public ReadOnly Property Errors() As String
        Get
            Return mstrErrors
        End Get
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        mstrErrors = ""
    End Sub
    Public Function MergeFiles(ByVal SourceFiles() As String _
                                , ByVal SourceTitles() As String _
                                , ByVal DestinationFile As String) As Boolean

        Dim boolReturnVal As Boolean = True

        'clear error variable
        mstrErrors = ""

        'If the destination merged PDF file exists, then delete it. 
        Try
            If System.IO.File.Exists(DestinationFile) = True Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(DestinationFile)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            mstrErrors = mstrErrors & " Cannot delete destination file:" & DestinationFile & ". Error is: " & ex.Message & vbCrLf
            boolReturnVal = False
        End Try

        If boolReturnVal = True Then 'if still true then continue!

            'Iterate the string array.
            For i As Int32 = 0 To UBound(SourceFiles) - 1

                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                '
                '
                ' !!!!   FINISH THIS CODE    - MERGE THE PDF's       !!!!!!!
                '
                '
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''





                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
                'Ensure OUTLINES are created in the destination PDF file!!!!!
                'The TITLES passed in SourceTitles are the OUTLINES. 
                '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            Next

        End If

        Return boolReturnVal

    End Function



    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    '
    '
    ' Here is a C# example of how to use the class.
    '
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    '
    '                using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument())
    '            {
    '                pdf.PageMode = PdfPageMode.UseOutlines;
    '                pdf.Append("d:\\0000-2981A.pdf");
    '
    '                pdf.Append("d:\\0000-2981B.pdf");
    '                pdf.RemovePage(0);
    '
    '
    '                PdfOutlineItem root = pdf.OutlineRoot;
    '
    '                for (int i = 0; i < pdf.PageCount; ++i)
    '                {
    '                    int pgcount = i + 1;
    '                    PdfOutlineItem outlineForPage = root.AddChild("Page " + pgcount.ToString(), i);
    '                }
    '
    '                pdf.Save(pathToFile);
    '            }




End Class
```

Please can any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question could be more specific. I am not sure I understood it right, but please try following sample code.

The sample code combines different documents into one PDF file and creates bookmarks. Each bookmark points to the first page of original document. Bookmarks titles are provided as parameter to the function.

Please note that the code is *auto-converted from C#*.

```
Public Shared Sub MergeFiles(sourceFiles As String(), bookmarkTitles As String(), destination As String)
    Using pdf As New PdfDocument()
        Dim targetPageIndex As Integer = 0
        For i As Integer = 0 To sourceFiles.Length - 1
            Dim currentName As String = sourceFiles(i)

            If i = 0 Then
                pdf.Open(currentName)
            Else
                pdf.Append(currentName)
            End If

            pdf.OutlineRoot.AddChild(bookmarkTitles(i), targetPageIndex)
            targetPageIndex = pdf.PageCount
        Next

        pdf.PageMode = PdfPageMode.UseOutlines
        pdf.Save(destination)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Here is the C# version for the reference:

```
public static void MergeFiles(string[] sourceFiles, string[] bookmarkTitles, string destination)
{
    using (PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument())
    {
        int targetPageIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sourceFiles.Length; i++)
        {
            string currentName = sourceFiles[i];

            if (i == 0)
                pdf.Open(currentName);
            else
                pdf.Append(currentName);

            pdf.OutlineRoot.AddChild(bookmarkTitles[i], targetPageIndex);
            targetPageIndex = pdf.PageCount;
        }

        pdf.PageMode = PdfPageMode.UseOutlines;
        pdf.Save(destination);
    }
}
```